# Updating nested cache in Apollo GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, graphql, apollo

I am fetching a list of documents from the backend using this query:

```
gql`
  query GetUserDocuments($userId: Int!, $filters: DocumentFilter) {
    user(userId: $userId) {
      id
      documents(filters: $filters) {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

The following object is saved in the Apollo cache

```
User:{"userId":123}
```

which has 2 nested collections defined inside

```
documents({"filter":{"archived": false}})
documents({"filter":{"archived": true}})
```

the apollo cache looks something like this

```
User:{"userId":123} {
  __typename: "User",
  userId: 123,
  documents({"filter":{"archived": false}}): []
  documents({"filter":{"archived": true}}): []
}
```

On the frontend, I would like to handle this cache so that when I archive a given document, I remove it from the collection `documents({"filter":{"archived": false}})` and I want to put it in the collection `documents({"filter":{"archived": true}})`. Similarly, when I unarchive a document, I remove it from the archived list and add it to the unarchived list. Is it possible to do this using a cache update? Or do I have to refetch the data, which I would like to avoid?

I tried using cache.modify, however I am getting 2 collections at the same time:

```
cache.modify({
  id: cache.identify({ __typename: "User", userId }),
  fields: {
    documents: (documents) => {
      return documents;
    },
  },
});
```